# rather a + adj + noun

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, british-english, ambiguity

> When the noun is preceded by an adjective both ***rather a*** (more
> typical of British English) and *a rather* are found.
>
> When *a rather* is used, *rather* qualifies only the adjective,
> whereas with **rather a** it qualifies either the adjective or the
> entire noun phrase. Thus *a rather long ordeal* can mean only "an
> ordeal that is rather long," whereas ***rather a** long ordeal* can
> also mean roughly "a long process that is something of an ordeal."
>
> https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rather

What is in effect the difference with "a long process that is something of an ordeal" ? Maybe a different example would help here.

Comment: The author regards _rather a long ordeal_ as implying _rather an ordeal_ that was also long - that is, it wasn't definitely an ordeal but only somewhat unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

I simply disagree with your source.

What it is saying is that

> rather a long ordeal

may mean that it definitely was long but was perhaps not an ordeal or that it definitely was an ordeal but was perhaps not long. I do not subscribe to that. I think that what is being qualified is the whole phrase, and that the construction is like "quite a" and "almost a" and "virtually a." That is "rather a long ordeal" indicates that the statement is a bit hyperbolic and not to be taken literally.

I do agree that

> a rather long ordeal

is primarily qualifying the adjective.